# Is DataGridView right for my purpose, without dataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, visual-studio-2015

I haven't been able to confirm if datagridview is right for my purpose, and hoping for some guidance.

I need a grid that displays links to file & folders in a project directory. The user will select a project from a combobox (projects stored in datatable), and that project's files & folders should appear in the datagridview. Since I'm not storing folder/file information in a datatable, the information to be shown in my datagridview will not come from a datatable... and this is the source of my uncertainty since it appears that's what datagridview seems mainly used for. 
Functionality needs to include: opening files/folders by clicking on the links, drag & drop the files to other folders, mouseover preview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Showing files and folders in a flat structure doesn't seem to be friendly, specially regarding to your requirement for drag & drop files and folders. It seems a treeview is more suitable for your requirement. By the way, not having data in a `DataTable` doesn't prevent you from showing data in `DataGridView`. You can show any list type like `List<T>` in `DataGridView`. Furthermore, you can convert any list type to `DataTable` if you need.

Comment: Thanks Reza - that's very helpful particularly to know DataTable isn't actually necessary for DataGridView. Treeview does appear to be better for me in this instance.